# How do you append to a variable string in a script?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, text-processing

How do I append a string that has variables in it?

```
sed 's/MIMG109AL1ARP\t[[:alnum:]]*\t/ /g'
```

I initially thought `sed`, but I don't want to replace anything, I want to add something after the intial line.

Some example strings are as follows:

```
MIMG109AL1ARP     PQHDO0542I7537

MIMG109AL1ARP     PQHDO0372I2435

MIMG109AL1LLL     QRHDO0382I2342

MIMG109AL1LLL     PQHDO362I2345
```

However I want them to look like this:

```
MIMG109AL1ARP     PQHDO0542I7537     appendagehere

MIMG109AL1ARP     PQHDO0372I2435     appendagehere

MIMG109AL1LLL     QRHDO0382I2342     appendage2here

MIMG109AL1LLL     PQHDO362I2345      appendage2here
```

Just edited the file to make my question more clear! I need to append separate lines separately, not every line. Thank you for your input so far.
Any help or redirection is appreciated!

Comment: `awk '$1~/^[A-Z]/ {print $0 "\tappendagehere"}' file`... Or, if you want `sed`: `sed '/^[A-Z]/ s/$/\tappendagehere/' file`

Comment: maybe use `vi` and learn to love the `A` (append to end-of-line)  and `.` (repeat-last-command) commands.  for a few dozen or a few hundred lines it's often easier and quicker to edit manually with a decent editor (such as vi).

Comment: ah I would but there is over 1000 lines I would need to edit unfortunately, and it's a script I wanted to create because it's a command I would need to run a couple times a year :(

Comment: But I think you guys really got me on the right track so far. When I finish troubleshooting I will make sure to upvote the answer :)

Comment: of those 1000+ lines, how many different matches are there?  and how many different strings need to be appended?

Comment: There were 9 different groups all of which needed a separate appendage! I added the solution after I asked my friend who is in a computer science masters program. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: see my perl script below.

Answer (score 1):

In sed, `$` represents the end of the line.  So you can say

```
sed -e 's/$/\twhatever/'
```

If you want to append only to non-empty lines, but leave empty lines empty, then use the following (where `&` in sed is the matched string, which in this case is one character):

```
sed -e 's/.$/&\twhatever/'
```

Or you can also just only do the substitution on non-empty lines:

```
sed -e '/./s/$/\twhatever/'
```

Comment: This breaks on empty lines...

Comment: it doesn't exactly break on empty lines, it just applies to them too.  if you don't want to append `\t whatever` to empty lines, use `sed -e 's/^.\+$/&\twhatever/'` instead.  or `sed -e 's/^[A-Z0-9a-z]\+[[:space:]]\+[A-Z0-0a=z]\+$/&\twhatever/'`

Comment: @cas I'll rephrase to accomodate your baseless nitpicking: "it produces unwanted output on emtpy lines, which in the real world is functionally equivalent to breakage."

Comment: it's not up to you to decide if it's "unwanted output".  in some cases, that may be **exactly** what is wanted.  saying that that is "broken" is, well, broken.

Comment: @jasonwryan: I didn't realize you had empty lines in your example, but I guess your transcript does.  See my revised answer, which has two ways to do what you want.

Comment: @cas Seriously? Look at the output specified in the question: do you see anything on the empty lines? No. So please continue your trolling elsewhere.

Comment: try to see beyond the specific question to the generic technique.  someone may be searching for how to do exactly what you have described as "broken" and give up because "it's broken".  i have NFI why you have decided to be so touchy and irritable but my comments were in no way intended to be trolling or nitpicking.

Comment: btw, you can't even be certain that the OP's original input contained empty lines - he may have added them in the question for readability.  people do that.

Answer (score 1):

With some help from one of my friends, I was able to get it to work using this line!

```
sed 's/\(MIMG109AL1ARP..*\)\($\)/\1\twhatIwant\2/g'
```

The solution was to break up the expression into two sub expressions. Instead of changing what I already had, I was able to flank what I wanted between the two sub-expressions.

Thank you both for posting and trying to help me out.

Comment: if you considered answers helpful, you should flag them as such.

Comment: Thanks, I did, but because I'm a new user with less than 15 rep, they don't show up yet!

Answer (score 0):

With only 9 different patterns and appendages to deal with, try something like this:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my %append = ( # matchregex       => appendstring
               qr/^MIMG109AL1ARP/ => 'appendagehere',
               qr/^MIMG109AL1LLL/ => 'appendage2here',
               # more here
             );

while (<>) {
   chomp;
   foreach my $re (keys %append) {
       if (m/$re/) {
           s/$/\t$append{$re}/;
           last;
       }
   }
   print $_, "\n";
}
```